# How to avoid getting the type Product With Serializable while creating a Merged maps from two different maps

Tags: java, scala, merge, hashmap, case-class

I am trying to merge below two maps.

```
var mutMap1: Map[String, List[CaseClass1]] = Map.empty[String, List[CaseClass1]]

var mutMap2: Map[String, List[CaseClass2]] = Map.empty[String, List[CaseClass2]]
var mergedMap = (mutMap1.keySet ++ mutMap2.keySet) map { i => i -> (mutMap1.get(i).toList ::: mutMap2.get(i).toList) } toMap
```

The type of mergedMap is `Map[String,List[List[Product with Serializable]]]`

```
But i am expecting this: Map[String,List[List[CaseClass3]]]
```

Where CaseClass3 is as below

```
case class CaseClass3(
                         caseClass1: List[CaseClass1],
                         caseClass1: List[CaseClass2]
                       )
```

Can someone please let me know how to specify the type to avoid getting `Product with Serializable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
val mergedMap: Map[String, CaseClass3] =
  (mutMap1.keySet ++ mutMap2.keySet).map { i => i -> CaseClass3(mutMap1.getOrElse(i, List()), mutMap2.getOrElse(i, List())) }.toMap
```